# How to restore Startup Manager Bootcamp option to point at Windows partition - GRUB overrided Startup Manager when Ubuntu installed

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, startup, dual-boot

For getting macOS, Windows 10 and Ubuntu as boot options at start up, I:

- ran Bootcamp to install Windows 10. The result was macOS and Windows options available as boot options - when the option-key is held down on starting the Mac.
- then, to add Ubuntu as a 3rd option to the Apple Startup Manager options, I followed [this guide - an answer to Installing Ubuntu on Mac with macOS and Windows already installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257275/4018)

However, the outcome is that:

- the Bootcamp option no longer boots into Windows. What happens is that there is a short delay and then it boots into macOS.
- Booting into Ubuntu works - selecting this option at the Startup Manager launches GRUB, which has options to boot Ubuntu and Windows. The Windows option here works, Windows is booted.

So it seems that the Ubuntu installer has looked for Windows and in my words, "taken it away" from the Startup Manager and linked it to GRUB.

How can I edit the original Apple Startup Manager settings so that the Bootcamp option is reconnected to the Windows partition so it boots it?

I've already looked at:

- [Mac won't boot Windows partition after using disk utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217527/mac-wont-boot-windows-partition-after-using-disk-utility/217528)
- [Broke Boot Camp while trying to get a triple boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175141/broke-boot-camp-while-trying-to-get-a-triple-boot)
- [Boot Camp partition broken and can't be repaired in OS X 10.10.4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196688/boot-camp-partition-broken-and-cant-be-repaired-in-os-x-10-10-4/272768)
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6465316
- [Fix Windows after Ubuntu installation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352838/fix-windows-after-ubuntu-installation)

...and they are related but all I really need is to link up the Apple Startup Manager boot option for Windows to the Windows partition again.

Windows itself still works, but has to be booted through selecting the option in GRUB which I did not want.